# Dealing with double navigation when coming from iOS apps

Tags: mobile, navigation, ios

When opening a link within an iOS app, it opens a browser directly inside the app. So you get the navigation from Facebook app and the navigation from the web app/website

[image]

What is the best way to deal with this behavior? (on Android, apps opens the system default browser by default, except the last Facebook app)
.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can control that the site is opened in a webview under other apps (I don't think so). There is no way to deal with it, some apps open the sites in-app, some others do it in the browser (safari). You can't do anything about it.

Maybe the best way to deal with it is basically avoid fixed headers in mobile webs, so you will have only one fixed header for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Flow would be like:

1. User comes to x screen.
2. Tap on link/button or any other mean to open url.
3. Then parent will push a y controller class (having uiwebview) along with setting parameter like url which would be required for webview.
4. Along pushing you need to add a tap gesture in your y controller( one tap or double tap detection).
5. On tap gesture method you would hide/show navigation bar (the top most).
6. Rest you need to change bounds to webview as per navigation bar is hidden/shown.